# $p\in\mathbb Z$ ramified in $R\Rightarrow p|\operatorname{disc}(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

The one in the title is Theorem 24, page 72 in the Marcus book "Number Fields".

I have a problem with a detail in the last part of the proof.

We have $\mathbb Q\le K$ and $L$ is a normal extension of $K$. Let $\mathbb Z, R, S$ be the corresponding number rings (i.e. $\mathbb Z=\mathbb A\cap\mathbb Q$, $R=\mathbb A\cap K$ and $S=\mathbb A\cap L$).

Let $p$ be a prime of $\mathbb Z$ ramified in $R$. Hence exists a prime of $R$, call it $P$ s.t. has ramification index $=e>1$.

I.e. $pR=PI$ where $I=P^{e-1}P_2^{e_2}\dots P_r^{e_r}$ is the product of all primes of $R$ lying over $p$.

Now it's clear that $pR\subsetneq I$ hence we can take $\alpha\in I\setminus pR$. Also, $\alpha$ is in every prime of $S$ lying over $p$. Call $Q$ one of these primes of $S$: it's $\alpha\in Q$.

My problem is: why has to be $\sigma(\alpha)\in Q\;\;\forall\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(L)$?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure of the entire set up but I think the fact is, that $\sigma$ permutes the primes lying above $p$. And since $\alpha$ is in all of these primes, the claim should be obvious.